# Can 2 columns from separate tables with a relationship both be auto_incremented?

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering because I heard that you should not do this- however when I did, my relationships seemed to work fine. If I don't autoincrement both columns (which are int values), the relationships fail to work properly. So I was just wondering if somebody could give a definite answer and explain why this may be the case?

Comment: Yes , every table in a db can have an auto_increment column if that's what you want. But it's unlikely that the columns will ever have a meaningful relationship between the tables. And there is an argument for saying auto_increment columns should have no business meaning but they are useful in other ways(which you should research). It's up to you to build your db so that meaningful relationships between tables can be established.

Comment: @P.Salmon Alright yeah, because the issue with mine is with user IDs. If I don't auto_increment every table/column that has a relationship with the user IDs, then the first value for the ID is 0, and then the relationship doesn't work at all. But now that I've auto_incremented everything, its all worked out. Thanks for the clarification.